# How do I use a lens with an IxSet?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Say, I have Users contained in a Userlist, like so:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.At -- maybe this would help?
import Data.IxSet

data User = User { _userId :: Int
                 , _userName :: String }

instance Indexable User where
    empty = ixSet [ ixFun (\u -> _userId u) ]

makeLenses ''User

data Userlist = Userlist { _users :: IxSet User }

makeLenses ''Userlist
```

What command would give me a lens to view, say, the 3rd member of a userlist?

Perhaps, since my data definition would allow multiple users with the same ID, a lens may not be what I want... a traversal? a prism?

Part of the difficulty for me is that all my googling leads me to a deprecated package called data-lens-ixset.

Comment: Don't you mean `instance Indexable…`?

Comment: Perhaps the best answer is "don't". You could use the tables package instead of  ixset.